# Geodjango and hierarchical locations

Tags: django, gis, postgis, hierarchical-data, geodjango

In a few weeks I want to start building a "datawarehouse" based on django. The database should be filled with data which can be connected to a location. For example population which is connected to country or city, or the anual rainfall or temperature. The parameters are not yet defined and will change over time but they will in general have a quantity, timeperiod (for example anual) and unit (so in the example: population of country X in year Y).

My idea was to have a selfreferencing table in the database named locations in which there would be continents, countries, regions and cities. An example:

```
ID | parent_id | name
1  | null      | Europe
2  | 1         | France
3  | 2         | Paris
```

I would than have a table which would connect data to a location like such:

```
ID | location_id | parameter_id | from_date  | to_date    | quantity
1  | 3           | 1            | 01-01-2000 | 31-01-2001 | 3000000
```

parameters:
    ID | name       | unit
    1  | population | people

Technically I also want to couple locations to coordinates or polygons such that I can show them on a map.

Is something like this possible in (Geo)Django? I feel that GeoDjango couples a model class to a specific subject such as in this case population. However, I do not know my subjects yet..

Or should I design the database structure different altogether?

Lastly: I want to use a pgSQL with postgis database for this because it is opensource and seems most appropriate. However if I program the website locally I have SQLite, is there a way I can run a pgSQL with Postgis locally on my windows computer (which is rather slow) for development? Can I then easily push it using for example GitLab to a production location (for example amazone AWS)?

Tips and help on this subject is very much appreciated.

Comment: Here check out the [django-cities](https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities) library for the idea, I think they are doing something similar, especially check out their example [country.io](http://country.io/) web page, as for psql and postgis, yes you can have it, check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/) they will guide you on how to setup it

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Django-cities looks very interesting but if I look at the code (I might be mistaken cause I'm relatively new to Django) it seems that there are different tables in the DB for: continents, countries, regions, cities. Does this work well if I for example want to couple data (for example population) to a country if I have country level data and to a city if I have city level data?

Also, does this support GIS polygons (for a country for example) or just points in the DB?

Comment: Yes I don't see a problem in that, you should definitely read more about it in django model [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/), especially [relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#relationships) part of models

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but if I have a table (or model), how does it know to which table the foreign key is refering? If I keep it simple and say I have a population table, how would I connect this to cities, countries, regions, continents (or some other location identifier)?

Answer (score 2):

For hierarchical data with Django, use [Django MPTT](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
class Region(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(null=True, blank=True)

class Parameter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class RegionParameter(models.Model):
    region = TreeForeignKey(Region, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True...)
    param = models.ForeignKey(Parameter...)
    from_date = models.DateField()
    to_date = models.DateField()
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

You can add the geographic data only on the leafs or to all levels in the hierarchy.

Comment: Whats the rationale for 3 different models? Why not keep all records in Region? Can you give an example of how to add records into these models?

Comment: Need these imports: ```from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey```